Give Entra joined user local admin rights on machine
On Windows 11, I have a new machine that requires new users of that machine to initially login/join via Entra to the domain.  Is there a way to give certain users that log in to that machine admin rights besides giving them the local admin password?
Attempted to look in "Other Accounts" for the user after they had first logged in but was not seeing that user.

Let me google that for you: https://www.reddit.com/r/Intune/comments/17xd4b8/how_to_add_a_user_or_group_to_local_admin_using/?rdt=38575

You can assign the Virtual Machine Administrator Login role to users in Azure to allow them to sign in with administrator privileges on a VM without needing the local admin password.
On the Virtual Machine page, scroll down the left-hand menu and select IAM -> Add Role Assignment -> Assign the Role (Virtual Machine Administrator Login to whomever you want to give access to).


Done. Now test access by login as that user

Detailed steps are outlined here
